# SQLAlchemy: reflection on DBs with limited permissions?

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to reflect some tables from a legacy DB (have no control over how it is set up, can't change it). The schema has a ton of tables in it, most of which aren't relevant to me, and which I don't have access to. When I try to reflect from the tables I do have access to, SQLAlchemy errors out because it can't do a SHOW command on some table I don't care about. E.g.:

```
fooTable  = Table('foo', meta)
insp = reflection.Inspector.from_engine(eng)
insp.reflecttable(fooTable, include_columns=("id", "name"))

sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (OperationalError) (1142, "SHOW command denied to user 'xxx'@'yyy' for table 'bar'") 'SHOW CREATE TABLE `schema`.`bar`' ()
```

There is an FK in fooTable to barTable (not on the id or name columns), but since I have no read access to or interest in barTable at all I'd really just prefer if SQLAlchemy could ignore it. Is this possible? I would be OK with a solution that doesn't try to load any relations at all, since I just need to read the data in individual tables.